# How to connect to Azure data lake storage using presto on python?

Tags: python-3.x, hive, presto, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

so i need to use presto to connect to ADLS, now I have read hive can connect to adls and presto can be used to connect to hive, but I could not find a single article on how to connect to adls using hive using python.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to find the same kind of request from OP in past thread.

This answer from [@SachinSheth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5781104/sachin-sheth) might help you to accomplish your task.

Also adding the third-party links below:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/5781104/sachin-sheth

https://medium.com/azure-data-lake/connecting-your-own-hadoop-or-spark-to-azure-data-lake-store-93d426d6a5f4